# YouTube API C#: Set Video Privacy Settings on Upload

Tags: c#, youtube-api

According code sample:

```
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
Video newVideo = new Video();
newVideo.Title = "Test";
newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Animals", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
newVideo.Description = "Testing Testing Testing";
newVideo.Private = true;
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("C:\\test.wmv", "video/x-ms-wmv");
request.Upload(newVideo);
```

we have 2 interesting lines:

```
newVideo.Private = true;
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
```

If set `newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;` - it will be public video.
If set `newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = true;` - it will be private video. 
Parameter `newVideo.Private = true;` is unknown.

But YouTube have one more paramer - "access by link".
How do I make video accessible by link on upload?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932197/using-youtube-net-api-to-upload-and-set-a-video-as-unlisted

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using Youtube .net API to upload and set a video as unlisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932197/using-youtube-net-api-to-upload-and-set-a-video-as-unlisted)

Reposting this here, to get the question answered.

I wasn't even able to comment, because my rep is too low...